# Compare the values of 2 dictionaries and append values to list

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am learning python and i am trying to compare the values of keys in 2 dictionaries ( dict1, pickle). What i am trying to achieve here is that:

1.)  the new key-value pairs of `dict1` that are not available in `pickle` should be updated in `pickle` dictionary and if those values are not NULL, then those keys should be appended to `updated_keys` list.

2.) check if the `dict1` keys already exists in `pickle` dictionary , check if those keys corresponding timestamp values (any change in the timestamp)  are updated in `pickle` dictionary and whatever keys were updated in `pickle` dictionary should be appended to a  `updated_keys` list.

Any help/guidance would be appreciated.

input:

```
dict1 = {'TOOLSTEST-2512': 'null', 'TOOLSTEST-2511': '2022-03-27T00:38:41.506-0400', 'TOOLSTEST-2510': '2022-03-28T1:38:41.506-0400', 'TOOLSTEST-2509': 'null', 'TOOLSTEST-2508': 'null'}


pickle = {'TOOLSTEST-2512': 'null', 'TOOLSTEST-2511': 'null', 'TOOLSTEST-2510': '2022-03-28T2:38:41.506-0400', 'TOOLSTEST-2509': 'null'}
```

Code:

```
    updated_keys = []

for key in dict1.keys():
    if ( key not in pickle.keys() and dict1[key] == 'null' ):
        pickle[key] = dict1.get(key) 
    elif (key not in pickle.keys() and dict1[key] != 'null'):
        pickle[key] = dict1.get(key)
        updated_keys.append(key)
```

output:

```
updated_keys = ['TOOLSTEST-2511','TOOLSTEST-2510']
```

Comment: It is unwise to call your variable `pickle`, in case you eventually need to import the standard library `pickle` module.  The names will collide.

Answer (score 0):

```
diff = dict((k, v) for k, v in dict1.items() if v != 'null' and v != getattr(pickle, k, None))
updated_keys = diff.keys()
pickle = {**pickle, **diff}
```

> output: dict_keys(['TOOLSTEST-2511', 'TOOLSTEST-2510'])

This will update any val that is not 'null' or different to the val in pickle with the same key :D.

Comment: Thank you. When i tested the code, i found keys are getting added to updated_keys list even when the key value in dict1 is same as key value in pickle dictionary. updated_keys list should only be updated, if there is a change in the timestamp (the value of a key) in dict1 and pickle dict.

Comment: Hi Peter, as a general rule, you should practice TDD, and write tests or input and expected output, this is the best way for people to understand what you want, otherwise, you will always get inconsistencies with how people interpret your questions.

Comment: In the above solution: `if v != 'null' and v != getattr(pickle, k, None)` this is the condition for values to be considered as an update. feel free to modify it to satisfy your condition.